# Slow MySQL query using indexes

Tags: mysql, indexing

I have a Providers table that looks like:

```
| id  | lastName | firstName | middleName |
| --- | -------- | --------- | ---------- |
```

with the following indexes:

- Providers_lastName
- Providers_firstName
- Providers_lastName_firstName
- Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName

All my queries use a trailing wildcard in the lastName and firstName values:

```sql
SELECT * FROM Providers
WHERE lastName LIKE 'smi%'
ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC, middleName
LIMIT 0, 50
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM Providers
WHERE firstName LIKE 'mar%'
ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC, middleName
LIMIT 0, 50
```

I have approximately 7 million rows in this table. My queries by lastName are very fast. However, the ones by firstName are very slow. Is there anything I'm doing wrong here? What other index could I add to improve the performance of my firstName-only queries without changing or removing the order?

**Edit 1:**

`EXPLAIN` output for `lastName` query:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "69901.30"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Providers",
        "access_type": "range",
        "possible_keys": [
          "Providers_lastName",
          "Providers_lastName_firstName",
          "Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName"
        ],
        "key": "Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "lastName"
        ],
        "key_length": "143",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 59008,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 59008,
        "filtered": "100.00",
        "index_condition": "(`db_name`.`providers`.`lastName` like 'smi%')",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "64000.51",
          "eval_cost": "5900.80",
          "prefix_cost": "69901.31",
          "data_read_per_join": "158M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "firstName",
          "middleName",
          "lastName",
          // OTHER COLUMNS
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`EXPLAIN` output for `firstName` query:

```
{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "390813.95"
    },
    "ordering_operation": {
      "using_filesort": false,
      "table": {
        "table_name": "Providers",
        "access_type": "index",
        "possible_keys": [
          "Providers_firstName"
        ],
        "key": "Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName",
        "used_key_parts": [
          "lastName",
          "firstName",
          "middleName"
        ],
        "key_length": "309",
        "rows_examined_per_scan": 948,
        "rows_produced_per_join": 329914,
        "filtered": "5.27",
        "cost_info": {
          "read_cost": "357822.55",
          "eval_cost": "32991.40",
          "prefix_cost": "390813.95",
          "data_read_per_join": "883M"
        },
        "used_columns": [
          "id",
          "firstName",
          "middleName",
          "lastName",
          // OTHER COLUMNS
        ],
        "attached_condition": "(`db_name`.`providers`.`firstName` like 'mar%')"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Providers` (
  `id` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `middleName` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(35) DEFAULT NULL,
  /* Other columns */
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `Providers_firstName` (`firstName`),
  KEY `Providers_lastName` (`lastName`),
  KEY `Providers_lastName_firstName` (`lastName`,`firstName`),
  KEY `Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName` (`lastName`,`firstName`,`middleName`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

**Edit 2:**

Output of `SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%'` after running a `FLUSH STATUS`:

Query 1 (firstName):

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_commit",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_delete",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_discover",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_external_lock",
            "Value": "2"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_mrr_init",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_prepare",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_first",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_key",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_last",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_next",
            "Value": "1487176"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_prev",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd_next",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_update",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_write",
            "Value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Query 2 (lastName):

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_commit",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_delete",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_discover",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_external_lock",
            "Value": "2"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_mrr_init",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_prepare",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_first",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_key",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_last",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_next",
            "Value": "49"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_prev",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd_next",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_update",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_write",
            "Value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Edit 3**

Using `FORCE_INDEX(Providers_firstName)`:

`EXPLAIN` output for `firstName` query:

```
{
    "query_block": {
      "select_id": 1,
      "cost_info": {
        "query_cost": "389514.60"
      },
    "ordering_operation": {
        "using_filesort": true,
        "table": {
          "table_name": "Providers",
          "access_type": "range",
          "possible_keys": [
            "Providers_firstName"
          ],
          "key": "Providers_firstName",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "firstName"
          ],
          "key_length": "83",
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 329914,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 329914,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "index_condition": "(`db_name`.`providers`.`firstName` like 'mar%')",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "356523.20",
            "eval_cost": "32991.40",
            "prefix_cost": "389514.60",
            "data_read_per_join": "883M"
          },
        "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "firstName",
            "middleName",
            "lastName",
            // Other columns
          ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Handler counts:

```
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_commit",
            "Value": "1"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_delete",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_discover",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_external_lock",
            "Value": "2"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_mrr_init",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_prepare",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_first",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_key",
            "Value": "51"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_last",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_next",
            "Value": "168497"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_prev",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd",
            "Value": "50"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_read_rnd_next",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_savepoint_rollback",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_update",
            "Value": "0"
        },
        {
            "Variable_name": "Handler_write",
            "Value": "0"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Curious what’s the overall record counts for each query? (The ones in your samples, you limit 50 in your return but what’s the row count in both cases)

Comment: I suspect the order by is your issue.  A table scan may be occurring because the first order by field is not the col you are filtering on for the fname query.  Try selecting your records into a temp table, then select * order by from that.

Comment: @IlanP, the total record count for the `firstName` query is 168,497 and it takes approximately 20 seconds the first time I run it. The count on the other one is a lot less (30, 298), but even when pulling more records is way more efficient. For example, it only takes 1.5 milliseconds to retrieve all the records (456,194) with a lastName that starts with `s`.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and `EXPLAIN SELECT...`

Answer (score 0):

**Query 1**

```
WHERE lastName LIKE 'smi%'
ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC, middleName
```

probably uses this index.  (Please provide `EXPLAIN...`):

```
Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName
```

That works relatively efficiently because it can walk through the `smi...` part of the index.

I'm assuming that `SELECT *` fetches only 4 columns, and `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY`??  And that `Providers_lastName_firstName_middleName` is `INDEX(lastName, firstName, middleName)`, with an implicit `id` tacked on the end because it is InnoDB??

This means that the entire query can be run in the index.  `EXPLAIN` would confirm this by saying "Using index", which implies a "covering index".

Furthermore, this query touched only 50 rows -- because the index is so well tuned to both the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY`, that it could actually fold in the `LIMIT 50`, too.

**Query 2**

```
WHERE firstName LIKE 'mar%'
ORDER BY lastName ASC, firstName ASC, middleName

Providers_firstName
```

Can also walk through an index for `mar...`, but then has to reach over to the data to get the rest of the columns.

But none of the rest of the optimizations (covering, etc) apply.  You could add `INDEX(first, last, middle, id)` to make it fast.

This query could not fold in the `LIMIT`.

**A Note**

In the US, 10% of names start with the most common letter, "S".  (The "10%" is approximately the same worldwide, except the most popular letter may vary.)

The Optimizer had multiple ways to perform any query and picks the "best" based on limited information.  When it is clear that a range will be a big one (`WHERE lastName LIKE 'S%'`), it *may* choose to switch from using the index to simply discarding many of the rows.  I don't think this happened here, but again `EXPLAIN` would tell us.

More on creating optimal indexes: http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql

**After Explain**

If I read the `EXPLAINs` correctly, they both use the `INDEX(last, first, middle)`, thereby avoiding a sort.  Note also `"using_filesort": false`., This allows the queries to stop after `LIMIT 50`.

To gather more information, please run the following:

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

If the `Handler_write*` are `0`, then there was no sort.  Meanwhile, the sum of the `Handler_read* values gives you the number of rows (probably in the`INDEX`) that were touched.

I expect Query 1 to show a total of 50 for reads, since it (theoritically) could dive into the index at `smi` and grab the next 50 (or fewer) rows.  This should take very few milliseconds.

Query 2 is messier, since it will need to scan through lots of the index before finding 50 with that first name.  It won't be 7M, but it might be 50K rows.  This will probably take several seconds if the necessary part of the index is cached; or a few minutes if it is not.

There is no way to make Q2 as fast as Q1.  This *might* be faster for `mar%`, but slower for `m%`:  `INDEX(first, last, middle)`.  That is, it is risky to introduce such an index.

In most situations, `INDEX(a)` is redundant if you also have `INDEX(a,b)`.    That is, you have 2 indexes that can probably be dropped.

Comment: Thanks for your insights, @rick-james. I edited my question and added the `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output details. Any additional recommendation?

Comment: @Donovan - I added more.

Comment: I added the output of the session status. Like you said, the first query only touches 50 rows, while the other one ~1.5M. If adding an extra index won't help, what would you say the best solution is to improve the performance of the second query?

Comment: What do you get with `FORCE INDEX(Providers_firstName)`?  (Check `EXPLAIN` and `Handler` counts.)

Comment: Looks like the performance is pretty much the same forcing the `firstName` index. I added the output details.

Comment: The hope was that forcing that index would lead to fewer rows.  The risk is that it would help for `mar%` but hurt for some other value.